# How to expand the width size of Input in Semantic React UI?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm working with Reactjs project, and I use Semantic UI React to beautify the `Input`. However, it seems that `Input` is always showed in default size. How can I resize its horizontal width ?

- I follow the instruction on [Semantic UI React Home page](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage), I put this line of code to Html:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.12/semantic.min.css"></link>`

- In js file I import:

`import { Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';`

- and render the input:

`<Input value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleInputFirstName}/>`

Comment: I've tried this `style={{ width: "300px" }}` but still didn't work.

Comment: If you take a look at the props for the Input component (https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input) you will see that `style` is not listed. However, `className` is, so you should be able to pass in a class that will do the same thing.

Comment: thanks for your response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding `style={{ width:"300px" }}` works perfectly fine for me. I am using same stylesheet as that of you. You can take a look at following code:

```
const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <h2>Start editing width and see magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
    <Input placeholder="Hello there" style={{width: "370px"}}/>
  </div>
);
```

Working example can be seen here:
[image: Edit StackOverflow 2]